# SFINAE to enable cast operator only from derived to base class

Tags: c++, templates, c++11, template-argument-deduction

I have a class template `CFoo<T>`. I want to allow implicit casts to other instantiations of `CFoo`, but only for those whose template argument is a base class of `T`.

I tried to use SFINAE, but neither of my attempts worked on any compiler I tried (VC 2012 or gcc):

```
#include <type_traits>

template <class T> class CFoo {
public:
    template <class Q>  operator
     // typename std::enable_if<std::is_base_of<Q, T>::value, CFoo<Q>&>::type   // SHOULD WORK?
     // typename std::enable_if<1, CFoo<Q>&>::type                              // SHOULD WORK?
     CFoo<Q>&  // compiles, but doesn't restrict on Q like I want
     () const {
        return *(CFoo<Q>*)this;
    }
};

class A {};
class B : public A {};

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    CFoo<B> b;
    CFoo<A>& a = b;
    return 0;
}
```

Why don't either of the commented out attempts at SFINAE work here? In both cases I just get an error for an invalid initialization of `a`, as if my operator didn't get called.

Comment: This has _poof_ written all over it.

Comment: `Q` isn't in a deduced context. But why on earth are you doing this?

Comment: @Captain O.  I don't understand!

Comment: @T.C.  Well we have this home grown smart pointer class, and a very large legacy codebase.  We have to manually downcast in a 100,000 places.  I'm overhauling the class and thought I'd make it implicitly downcast.  I don't want it to implicit upcast.  I didn't think this was a bad idea.  Is it?

Comment: I can see the use case for an `operator CFoo<Q>()`, though it might be easier to use a converting constructor instead. What you are currently doing is absolutely a bad idea. That C-style cast is a `reinterpret_cast` plus a `const_cast`, hint, hint...

Comment: @johnnycrash Don't add answers to the questions.

Comment: @Barry, darn.  Should I take it out?

Comment: @TC, well I wanted to ensure that I went the highest performance route.  I figured, probably incorrectly, that creating temporary objects all over the place would be slower.  Is this what you mean by a converting constructor?

Comment: Can someone tell me what "this has poof written all over it means?"  I still don't get it.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

According to [temp.deduct.conv]:

> Template argument deduction is done by comparing the return type of the conversion function template (call
>   it P) with the type that is required as the result of the conversion (call it A; see 8.5, 13.3.1.5, and 13.3.1.6
>   for the determination of that type) as described in 14.8.2.5.

In the simple case:

```
template <class Q>
operator CFoo<Q>& const;
```

That's straightforward, we try to deduce `CFoo<Q>&` against `CFoo<A>&`. There's other rules in that section, but ultimately that deduction succeeds with `Q == A`.

Both of your other attempts fail for the same reason. I'll pick the simpler one:

```
template <class Q>
operator typename std::enable_if<1, CFoo<Q>&>::type const;
```

Here, we're trying to deduce `typename std::enable_if<1, CFoo<Q>&>::type`. This is a non-deduced context (it's a *nested-name-specifier*  of a type that was specified using a *qualified-id*), so deduction fails. So this conversion function won't be considered, so the assignment fails as no conversion is found.

You need the return type to be a deduced context, so the SFINAE has to go here:

```
template <class Q,
          typename = std::enable_if_t<std::is_base_of<Q, T>::value>>
operator CFoo<Q>& const;
```

That way, we have something to deduce (`CFoo<Q>&`) - and the deduction can succeed (if `Q` is a base of `T`):

```
CFoo<A>& a = b; // OK
CFoo<int>& i = b; // deduction failure on Q, so there's no viable conversion function
                  // so this is an error
```

---

That said, while I got carried away with solving template puzzles, as [T.C.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31569716/sfinae-to-enable-cast-operator-only-from-derived-to-base-class/31570089?noredirect=1#comment51095596_31570089) points out, this really isn't a good solution because:

```
return *(CFoo<Q>*)this;
```

just does a `reinterpret_cast` (and a `const_cast`) so it really cannot possibly be doing anything reasonable and you will almost certainly (unless `CFoo` is trivial) end up with undefined behavior by trying to access its members with the wrong type.

You probably instead want to add a conversion *constructor* rather than a conversion *function*:

```
template <typename Q,
          typename = std::enable_if_t<std::is_base_of<T, Q>::value>>
CFoo(CFoo<Q> const& ) { }
```

That way, when you do:

```
CFoo<A> a = b; // a is not a reference anymore
```

You are constructing a *new* object that will necessarily be valid.

Comment: YOU ROCK!  Now, can you fix c++ so in version c++20 we take this awesome template filtering functionality and make it SIMPLE.

Comment: @johnnycrash What's C++20?

Comment: This solves the deduction problem, but the bigger problem with OP's code is that virtually any use of the returned reference causes UB.

Comment: @Barry, c++20 doesn't exist yet, other than in my head.  Its where c++ expands and simplifies SFINAE.

Comment: @T.C. Very good point, I get carried away with template puzzles sometimes. Updated my answer.

Comment: In C++1z, we have `template<class Q> requires std::is_base_of<T,Q>{}() CFoo(CFoo<Q> const&) {}` which is marginally clearer than the conversion constructor example above.

Comment: Well it's a smart pointer class.  The const cast is because I stole the code from our smart pointer to constant.  So would the code be as big a problem if we eliminated const from the question?

Comment: @Yakk.  I think that is going in the right direction.  Whenever I try to code in other languages without c++ templates I don't care how crazy they look, I need the power.  My one pitiful gripe is that C++ seems a bit verbose right now in this area.